# Is there a property I can check to see if code is rendered using hydrate vs render?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app (with SSR) and need to handle things differently for server vs browser renders.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following, but my gut feeling is there is a better way.

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // This code is rendered in browser vs server
}
```